# Using KQL 'let' to combine two queries in the same result

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer

everything good? I'm trying to do monitoring for StorageBlobs through Azure monitoring using KQL. I would like to count the daily amount of files that go into each StorageBlobs "landing" folder. I would like to see this daily result and compare it with the result of 7 days ago to verify that there is not a drop in the intake of files in the folders and I would like to present the percentage in another column comparing how much was entered today compared to 7 days ago so that each day of the week compares with the same day of the previous week.
but without success!! Someone can help me, please?

**I'm testing the following code:**

```
let folders = view () {
    StorageBlobLogs
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
    | where OperationName has_any ("PutBlob", "PutBlock", "PutBlockList")
    | where Uri has_any ("landing")
    | where Uri !contains "catchall" and Uri !contains ".archive" and Uri !contains "azuretmpfolder"
    | extend feedSplit1 = tostring(split(Uri, "/2022/")\[0\])
    | extend feedSplit2 = tostring(split(feedSplit1, "/landing/")\[1\])
    // magic here
    | extend feedSplitF = replace_regex(feedSplit2, @"(\[\\/0-9\])","")
    // end of magic
    | extend feedSplit = tostring(split(Uri, '/')\[4\])
    | extend feed = column_ifexists('feedSplit', "")
    | extend feed = iif(feed == 2022, "", feed)
    | extend feed = iif(feed == 'loganalytics-export', strcat(split(Uri, '/')\[5\], "/", split(Uri, '/')\[6\]), feed)
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)}
;
let Weekago = view () {
    folders
    | where TimeGenerated < ago(6d)
    | summarize countweekago = count() by folder
};
let today = view () {
    folders
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
    | summarize counttoday = count() by folders
};
countweekago
| join today on $left.folder == $right.folders
| project countweekago, counttoday, folders
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but running tests now is showing the following error:
'join' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'countweekago'
If issue persists, please open a support ticket. Request id: 11152393-255b-4dae-a012-519a634123c5

Answer (score 0):

It should be "Weekago" and not "countweekago", "countweekago" is not declared